# Changing ssh ciphers on EC2 ubuntu

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm running ubuntu on an Amazon EC2 server - I need to lock down the ssh ciphers for pci compliance.  I have tried editing the   /etc/ssh/sshd_config, with these lines:

```
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
```

and restarted the server.  However, this command:

```
ssh -Q cipher localhost
```

still lists a full range of ciphers that I no longer want.  Is there some configuration I'm missing?

```
ssh version is OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
Linux is: Linux ip-172-31-34-22 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh -Q cipher` reports the ciphers supported by the ssh client, not the server.

One way to verify that you have successfully removed the cipher `foo` from the server configuration is to explicitly use it for your connection:

`ssh -oCiphers=foo localhost`

---

relevant excerpt from [`ssh.c`](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh.c?rev=1.445&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) option processing:

```
            case 'Q':
                    cp = NULL;
                    if (strcmp(optarg, "cipher") == 0)
                            cp = cipher_alg_list('\n', 0);
                    /* deleted other options... */
                    if (cp == NULL)
                            fatal("Unsupported query \"%s\"", optarg);
                    printf("%s\n", cp);
                    free(cp);
                    exit(0);
                    break;
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation - now when I run this:

ssh -oCipher=arcfour localhost

it asks for the password - arcfour isn't supposed to be allowed anymore per my list above, but for some reason it still is.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I mistyped.  The command should be `ssh -oCiphers=foo localhost`, not `ssh -oCipher=foo localhost` as my answer originally stated.  (Note that you did not get an error because the version *without* the plural is a valid configuration option, but means something different--namely, what cipher to use on ssh v1 connections.)

Comment: Oh, that actually made a difference - now it says "no matching cipher found", so perhaps I have things correct.  I'm re-running the scan now.